# How to parse first word of each lines from a file using batch—file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a n number of text files in folder with below format

File1.txt

```
001@12345    Value1 
002@12345    Value2
```

File2.txt

```
003@12345    Value3 
004@12345    Value4
```

I need to get the sum of numbers before @ symbol. How do I get this using windows batch script?

Comment: Fine. And what is your specific question? Please learn [ask] here! Remember that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service! So you have to try it on your own and come back here when you are stuck, providing a [mcve]! Also you need to clarify whether you want the sum per file or over all files...

Answer (score 2):

type the files, find relevant lines, put a `for /f` around to get the first part before the `@` and sum them up:

```
@echo off
set sum=0
for /f "delims=@" %%a in ('type file*.txt ^|find "@"') do set /a sum+=1%%a-1000
echo %sum%
```

Note: there are some restrictions: in the current form, it works only with three-digit-numbers and there is a limit for the sum due to the INT32 numbers. (max. 2147483647, but reduced by the trick to overcome numbers treated as octal, when starting with `0`)

Comment: This will unfortunately only work with numbers up to `7` because of the leading zeros which lets `set /A` interpret them as octal ones; also `type` outputs the file names at _STDERR_ when using wildcards...

Comment: @aschipfl ah, yes, I overlooked that. - edited.

Comment: To deal with the leading zeros you could also place another `for /F` loop inside of yours: `for /F "delims=@" %%a in ('2^> nul type "file*.txt" ^| find "@"') do for /F "delims=0" %%b in (""%a") do set /A "SUM+=%%b"`

Comment: @aschipfl, don't you need `TOKENS=* delims=0` to strip the leading zeros?

Comment: Oh yes, @Squashman, absolutely, sorry for missing that...